# Convert blob url to a URL which Capacitor Share plugin can use

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

Trying to share a pdf with capacitor's share plugin. I correctly get a blob url but the problem is that Capacitor's Share plugin can't use it. Is there a way to convert the blob url to something it can use?

```
async shareSurvey(surveyId) {
    this.http
      .get('https://specto.axi.be/stage/api/surveys/getPdf/' + surveyId, {
        responseType: 'blob',
      })
      .subscribe(async (res) => {
        console.log('Opgehaalde pdf:', res);

        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        console.log('OBJECT URL', objectURL);
        // blob:https://i367766.hera.fhict.nl/4a81a9bf-ca71-4492-b968-2ace9440c668

        await Share.share({
          title: 'Deel verslag',
          text: 'Deel je verslag als pdf.',
          url: objectURL,
          dialogTitle: 'Deel je verslag',
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('Error sharing file:', err);
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: save the PDF In server then return the URL or read the blob convert it to base64 url and then share it maybe In a query string or something (not recommended way - it's an expensive task specially hard for low end device's to convert to base64)

Comment: Thanks, I’ll ask the senior dev whether it’s possible to do it server side. So there’s no other alternative to this?